# Initializing constant array of type struct

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am unable to initialize a constant array of a custom type. Following is the code:

```
union chk {
    struct{
        int a : 4;
        int b : 12;
    }stNative;
    int nVal;
};

const chk obj[2] = {0x1234, 0x6789};

int main() {
    
    cout << obj[0].nVal<<endl;
}
```

On Executing the above code, I get some random values.
I am not able to understand the reason this is happening and how can it be fixed.
O/P of the above code is : 30868

Comment: what random values? Please include the output in the question

Comment: The union initialiser only initialises `stNative`, as you've only provided a single value `b` is left uninitialised https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes all `#include` directives and `using` declarations. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: I have some issues with the word "random". Why do you call it random? I can run the code several times and the output is always the same

Comment: @user17732522 ok I'll undelete. My answer to your comment still holds, i'll remove it nevertheless ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number OK, nevermind. I checked and _named_ bitfields are considered elements for aggregate initialization, but _unnamed_ once are not.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah I just noticed the output is same everytime.

Comment: what is correct expected output? (And why are you using a union? Why bitfields?)

Comment: I got my answer. I had made 2 mistakes. 1. Integer overflow was happening. 2. Union data structure initialization happens only for the first field. I did not know this. Thanks @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you cannot test undefined behavior. You cannot see if a member was not initialized by printing its value

Answer (score 5):

Initialization in declaration assigns the values to the first union member `stNative`, that is a struct with two values. You have provided the values for the first struct member `a` with overflow. This small update will initialize both the struct members.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union chk {
    struct{
        int a : 4;
        int b : 12;
    }stNative;
    int nVal;
};

const chk obj[2] = {{0x1, 0x234}, {0x6, 0x789}};

int main() {
    // Undefined behaviour bellow while reading nVal
    cout << std::hex << obj[0].nVal<<endl;
}
// Output: 2341
```

Type punning is not allowed in C++. If you initialize the union member `stNative`, then should read it only, reading `nVal` is not allowed. Use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) or `memcpy` for type punning.

Answer (score 0):

In C++20, you can do this to initialize that particular member explicitly:

```
union chk {
    struct {
        int a : 4;
        int b : 12;
    } stNative;
    int nVal;
};

int main() {
    const chk obj[2] = {{.nVal = 0x1234}, {.nVal = 0x6789}};
}
```

Comment: why does OPs code produce the output is does produce? Thats the question

Comment: *and how it can be fixed* is also the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I believe OP's intention is to spread the value of the hex literals (through nVal) over the bitfields. This answer shows how to do that.

Comment: well yeah, I reread the quesiton and actually there is no question :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number To initialize, or not to initialize. That is the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that in this particular case you were victimised by [**brace elision**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation) of embedded aggregate type:

> The braces around the nested initializer lists may be elided
> (omitted), in which case as many initializer clauses as necessary are
> used to initialize every member or element of the corresponding
> subaggregate, and the subsequent initializer clauses are used to
> initialize the following members of the object.

So while you think that you initialise the `int nVal` property of the union, you in fact initialise the `struct stNative`. The reason for that is (as pointed out in the [273Ks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73246486/5690248)) because the struct member comes first in the declaration of the union.

If brace ellision was not a thing, you array initialisation would have to look something like this (or otherwise would be considered ill-formed):

```
const chk obj[2] = {{ 0x1234, 0x6789 }};
```